# How to center a CGImage on a CALayer?

Tags: swift, calayer, cgimage

I was trying to set a `UIImage`'s `CGImage` as a `layer`'s content and then add the `layer` to a `view`'s `layer`.
It's should be five stars at the center of the yellow view. That's what I want it to be.
But it seems the center of the stars is aligned with the `origin` of the `view`.
What should I do to rectify it?

```
func putOnStars() {
    let rect = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    rect.backgroundColor = .yellow
    view.addSubview(rect)

    let baseLayer = CALayer()
    baseLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "stars")?.cgImage
    baseLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
    rect.layer.addSublayer(baseLayer)

}
```

[image]
Here is the stars image for you in case of you want to test.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`baseLayer` doesn't have a defined frame so `baseLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter` will work fine but it'll still be on the potision (0, 0).

There are two possible solutions:

1 : Make a frame of `baseLayer` that is identical to `rect`. Implement this code:

```
baseLayer.frame = rect.frame
```

2 : Set the position of `baseLayer` to the center of `rect`. Implement this code:

```
baseLayer.position = rect.center
```

Comment: Thanks man. I thought there is no need for setting the frame.

Answer (score 4):

To place the `stars` `image` in the centre of the `CALayer`, give the `frame` of the layer, i.e.

```
    let baseLayer = CALayer()
    baseLayer.frame = rect.bounds //This Line
    baseLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "stars")?.cgImage
    baseLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter
    rect.layer.addSublayer(baseLayer)
```

For any kind of `CALayer`, you need to define its `frame` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but I will adapt Cyan's answer because he is earlier.

Comment: Sure..no issues..Happy coding..:)